# Xcode 6 - SWIFT - Error accessing an array

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode6

```
var files = ["Sound1", "Sound2", "Sound3", "Sound4", "Sound5"]
var fileLocation = NSString(string:  NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Sounds/" +  files[2] , ofType: "mp3")!)
```

I'm trying to create an app that plays random sounds, but i get this error :

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

The code works fine if i specified which sound i would like to play, but crashes when i try to access the array.

PS: There are no misspellings at all.

Comment: Are you sure "Sound3.mp3" exists in the "Sounds/" directory? Have the checked the created .app?

Comment: Yes, if i replaced ' "Sounds/" +  files[2]' with '"Sounds/Sound3" '  it works !

Comment: What is `fileLocation` immediately after the allocation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite weird situation because the same code is not reproducible for me.

As a general solution, it might help if you use a dedicated overload of pathForResource:

```
NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(files[2], ofType: "mp3", inDirectory: "Sounds")
```

Comment: Removing the folder name did work, for some reason ?!, Thanks Nevs

Comment: I don't understand why this would make a difference.

Comment: @ThomasW Me neither !, everytime i get the hand of (!) and (?) something strange happens !!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var fileLocation = NSString(string:  NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Sounds/\(files[2])", ofType: "mp3")
```

Comment: Did that before and it didn't work, removing the folder name completely made it work !!